# Printing word document with margins out of printable area

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I have a code where i am printing word document.
In the sample document there is a section with picure that has modified margins by user.

When i execute the code I recieve following message:

> The margin of section 1 are set outside of printable area.

After processing document, it starts spooling and throws this promt
[image]
How do i turn the notification dialog box off?

**my code so far:**

```
        Process printJob = new Process();
        printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
        printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
        printJob.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        printJob.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        printJob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
        printJob.Start();
```

Where variable path > is file name path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/OutsidePrintableArea.htm

According to this, you'll need to turn off background printing, then turn off Application.DisplayAlerts.

**EDIT**

You're not going to be able to do this with `Process`. The "print" verb uses /x /dde to tell Word to print:

> /x Starts a new instance of Word from the operating shell (for example, to print in Word). This instance of Word responds to only one DDE request and ignores all other DDE requests and multi-instances. If you are starting a new instance of Word in the operating environment (for example, in Windows), it is recommended that you use the /w switch, which starts a fully functioning instance.

To suppress the message, you're going to need to do interop instead:

1. Add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
2. Make a `Print(string path)` method:

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;

//object missing = Type.Missing;

wordApp.Documents.Open(path); //for VS 2008 and earlier - just give missing for all the args

wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(false); //as before - missing for remaining args, if using VS 2008 and earlier

wordApp.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges); //ditto
```

Comment: I do not see how this will help me as i have no application but console.

Comment: See my edit. Process printing is nice when your requirements are very simple.

Comment: that whas what i have been missing. Do you know how to force it to print double sided?

Comment: (wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone; still pops up the prompt for me.)

Comment: @cederlof Is background printing also off?

Comment: @sq33G As in PrintOut(false)? Yes. I just posted a lengthy question on the subject at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720465/print-word-document-from-wpf-with-print-settings-aspose-generated :)

Comment: (wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone; does not work for me either. Still get the dialog and messes up my code.